How to find a closed form for the summation $\sum_{r = 1} ^ {n} \frac{r + 1}{3 ^ r(2r - 1)(2r + 1)}$?
What I have tried so far:
Let $T_n$ equal to the required summation. Notice that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{3}T_n &= \sum_{r = 1} ^ {n} \frac{r + 1}{3 ^ {r + 1}(2r - 1)(2r + 1)} \\ 
&=\sum_{r = 2} ^ {n + 1}\frac{r}{3 ^ r(2r + 1)(2r + 3)}.
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
\frac{2}{3}T_n = T_n - \frac{1}{3}T_n &= \left(\sum_{r = 1} ^ {n} \frac{r + 1}{3 ^ r(2r - 1)(2r + 1)}\right) - \left(\sum_{r = 2} ^ {n + 1}\frac{r}{3 ^ r(2r + 1)(2r + 3)}\right) \\
&= \left(\sum_{r = 2} ^ {n} \frac{1}{3 ^ r(2r + 1)}\left(\frac{r + 1}{2r-1} - \frac{r}{2r + 3}\right)\right) + \frac{2}{3\cdot 1\cdot3} - \frac{n + 1}{3 ^ {n + 1}(2n + 3)(2n + 5)} \\
&= \left(\sum_{r = 2} ^ {n} \frac{1}{3 ^ r(2r + 1)}\frac{6r + 3}{(2r-1)(2r + 3)}\right) + \frac{2}{3\cdot 1\cdot3} - \frac{n + 1}{3 ^ {n + 1}(2n + 3)(2n + 5)} \\
&= \left(\sum_{r = 2} ^ {n} \frac{3}{3 ^ r(2r-1)(2r + 3)}\right) + \frac{2}{3\cdot 1\cdot3} - \frac{n + 1}{3 ^ {n + 1}(2n + 3)(2n + 5)}.
\end{align}
So now the key seems to be finding a closed formula for
$$\sum_{r = 2} ^ {n} \frac{3}{3 ^ r(2r-1)(2r + 3)}.$$
However, I don't seem to have any idea about how to approach this summation.
Could someone provide some hints or suggest another better approach?

$$\frac{r+1}{(2r-1)(2r+1)} = \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{3}{2r-1} - \frac{1}{2r+1}\right),$$
so
$$a_r = \frac{r+1}{3^r(2r-1)(2r+1)} = \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{3^{r-1}(2r-1)} - \frac{1}{3^r (2(r+1)-1)} \right) = \frac{1}{4}(b_r - b_{r+1}),$$
where $$b_r = \frac{1}{3^{r-1} (2r-1)}.$$
Consequently the sum is telescoping:
$$\sum_{r=1}^n a_r = \frac{1}{4} \sum_{r=1}^n (b_r - b_{r+1}) = \frac{1}{4}(b_1 - b_{n+1}).$$

Wow, I haven't thought about this before. Thanks!
